# GROUPING multiple LIKE string

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-like

**Data:**

```
2015478 warning occurred at 20201403021545
2020179 error occurred at 20201303021545
2025480 timeout occurred at 20201203021545
2025481 timeout occurred at 20201103021545
2020482 error occurred at 20201473021545
2020157 timeout occurred at 20201403781545
2020154 warning occurred at 20201407851545
2027845 warning occurred at 20201403458745
```

In above data, there are 3 kinds of strings I am interested in warning, error and timeout
Can we have a single query where it will group by string and give the count of occurrences as below

**Output:**

```
timeout 3
warning 3
error 2
```

I know I can write separate queries to find count individually. But interested in a single query
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation for that:

```
select count(*) filter (where the_column like '%timeout%') as timeout_count, 
       count(*) filter (where the_column like '%error%') as error_count, 
       count(*) filter (where the_column like '%warning%') as warning_count
from the_table;
```

This returns the counts in three columns rather then three rows as your indicated.

If you do need this in separate rows, you can use `regexp_replace()` to cleanup the string, then group by that:

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, '(.*)(warning|error|timeout)(.*)', '\2') as what,
       count(*) 
from the_table
group by what;
```

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, The first query is what I need...
Perfectly worked..
Thank you so much....

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, without hard coding the values using `STRPOS`

```
select val, count(1) from
(select substring(column_name ,position(' ' in (column_name))+1,
length(column_name) - position(reverse(' ') in reverse(column_name)) - 
position(' ' in (column_name))) as val from  matching) qry
group by val;  -- Provide the proper column name
```

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jim, however for some reason I am unable to make it work. Really appreciate your time here

Comment: Provided you the new query along with the demo. Let me know if its helpful. Was trying to help you without hard coding the values in the query

Answer (score 0):

If you want this on separate rows you can also use a lateral join:

```
select which, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     (values (case when col like '%error%' then 'error' end),
             (case when col like '%warning%' then 'warning' end),
             (case when col like '%timeout%' then 'timeout' end)
     ) v(which)
where which is not null
group by which;
```

On the other hand, if you simply want the second word -- but don't want to hardcode the values -- then you can use:

```
select split_part(col, ' ', 2) as which, count(*)
from t
group by which;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=21c303b399f81695411d08707021c319) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, however for some reason I am unable to make it work. Really appreciate your time here

Comment: @SurajK . . . The second query worked as-is.  The first had a typo.  I added a db<>fiddle showing that both do what you want.